# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(4^n +n^5)} {n+3}$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(4^n +n^5)} {n+3}$$

I don't know how to solve this. Tried to use the sandwich theorem:

$$\frac{\ln(4^n +n^5)} {n+3} > \frac{\ln(4^n)} {n+3} = \frac{n\ln(4)} {n+3}=  
\ln(4)\frac{n} {n+3} $$

The limit of this at infinity is $\ln(4)$ which is the answer, But I can't find the upper bond.

Comment: You should show your work and effort.

Comment: Hint: $4^n+n^5=4^n(1+\frac{n^5}{4^n})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large $n$, we have that $n^{5}\leq4^{n}$. Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\ln\left(4^{n}+n^5\right)}{n+3} & \leq & \frac{\ln\left(4^{n}+4^{n}\right)}{n+3}\\
 & = & \frac{\ln\left(2\cdot4^{n}\right)}{n+3}\\
 & = & \frac{\ln2}{n+3}+\frac{n\ln4}{n+3}.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand, obviously, $\frac{\ln\left(4^{n}+5^{n}\right)}{n+3}\geq\frac{\ln4^{n}}{n+3}=\frac{n\ln4}{n+3}$.
Therefore, for large $n$,
$$
\frac{n\ln4}{n+3}\leq\frac{\ln\left(4^{n}+5^{n}\right)}{n+3}\leq\frac{\ln2}{n+3}+\frac{n\ln4}{n+3}.
$$
Clearly, $\frac{n\ln4}{n+3}\rightarrow\ln4$ and $\frac{\ln2}{n+3}+\frac{n\ln4}{n+3}\rightarrow\ln4$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$. By sandwich rule, it follows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln\left(4^{n}+5^{n}\right)}{n+3}=\ln4$.

Comment: While the system does give you a bit of grace between when a question is closed and when it is impossible to post an answer to that question, please do try to avoid abusing that grace period to post answers to questions which do not meet the quality standards of the site.  For reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/ .